# How to submit a form on input field onBlur event in ReactJS?

Tags: forms, reactjs, jsx

I have multiple form in a Screen. Need to submit form while onBlur event calling without using ref, because i have multiple and dynamic forms.

Comment: You can still use ref with multiple forms; have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks for your response Chris. Its a dynamic form.

Answer (score 0):

You may add onBlur event, get access to DOM-element Form and then do submit 'form.submit()':

```
const myForm = () =>
    <input onBlur={(e) => {
  // if click occurs outside of element
      if(!e.relatedTarget || (e.target.form !== e.activeTarget)) 
  //attention: your page will reload every such instant submission
        e.target.form.submit();
      }
    }} ... (other props) >
    ...
 </form>
```

Or you need to use

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => {
             e.preventDefault();
             ...
}>
    <input onBlur={(e) => {
             ...
             e.target.form.requestSubmit();
    } />
        
...
```

the detail of this solution are here [Here is my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67863099/how-to-prevent-page-reload-using-form-submit-to-submit-as-a-method-onblur-in-r)